# Set data attribute using string in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just starting out in react and I've got a tooltip as part of a cart that I need to set the text for.

```
<a href="#" class="psh-Delivery_Link tip-Tooltip" data-tooltip={{ window.theme.strings.pushCart.deliveryToolTipText }}>test</a>
```

so I went to set the `data-tooltip` attribute, but this is giving me an error. Also tried `data-tooltip="' + window.theme.strings.pushCart.deliveryToolTipText + '`

Comment: Please edit the question to show the error. That will help anyone trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
data-tooltip={{ window.theme.strings.pushCart.deliveryToolTipText }}
```

To

```
data-tooltip={window.theme.strings.pushCart.deliveryToolTipText }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the React tutorial on props](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props). In summary, if you want to send a prop that is a string you can simple enclose it in quotes.

```
<a prop="value">
```

Otherwise use **single** curly braces (in which you can write any JavaScript statement)

```
<a prop={value.foo}>
```